# How can I check that a function ran properly on C#

Tags: c#

Hi I'm writing a program in C# that uses a text file to manage user names and passwords (I know it's a bad way but it's a school project and my first time doing something like this).

I have a function that deletes a line in the text file:

```
static public void RemoveUser()
{
     Console.Clear();
     Console.WriteLine("Voer naam en wachtwoord in van de gebruiker die u wilt verwijderen."); //here i'm asking for the username and password of the user they want to delete
     string removedUser = Console.ReadLine();
     File.WriteAllLines("db.txt", File.ReadLines("db.txt").Where(l => l != removedUser).ToList());
}
```

When I run the function now and the user input is invalid(typo, non existent user) the code runs without error but doesn't do anything the the text file.
What I want now is to check if the function so that i can display an error when the user input is invalid, for example when they make a typo or try to delete a non existent user.

I've searched google for answers but couldn't find anything.

the text file looks like this:

```
Verkoper 2
Admin 3
Inkoper 1
```

Comment: Put the lines of text of the file in a variable and check with .Contains. This way you can make an error yourself if none of the lines match it

Comment: For school project, if the subject is not string manipulation. Go for class. If the propose is to store something in a file and retrieve it then that something is an object. It deserve a good name and properties. Then we have "from file to list customObject". And only real list object manipulation. And feeding the list is just read all split on separator pass it to an object constructor

Comment: But is the question about unit testing a function?

Comment: @DragandDrop The project is to make an entire program in C#. Deleting users from the text file is a part of it.

Comment: My English is bad but I wasn't talking about anything else than C#. It's basically working on a list of string is cool but with a list of object with properties is cooler. It's stand as  And my second comment is addressing your title. Verify the correct execution of an operation in a specific context is called unit testing. And your method take no argument and return nothing, making it harder to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load in your text file beforehand, and check whether any of the lines match the input, like so:

```
string user = Console.ReadLine();
string[] lines = File.ReadAllText("db.txt").Replace("\r", "").Split('\n');
if (!lines.Contains(user))
{
    //handle your invalid user here.
}
```

Comment: @Hollow, While this may works. It's a contains on the lines. Not password or login on whatever information you are storing. It will delete lines if the users name in contains in a password. And if your user to delete is Space `" "`, then you've deleted all the lines.

Comment: @DragandDrop "Contains" matches the whole element, no? Not a substring of the element. Yes this is a pretty janky method, but using " " would not delete all users.

Comment: Yes, My bad. It's not String Contains but Array Contains. So he must time the exact lines to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if user exists in the file before trying to remove it:

```
var users = File.ReadAllLines("db.txt")
       .Select(l => var u = l.Split(' '); return new {Name = u[0], Id = u[1]}).ToList();

string removedUser = Console.ReadLine();
if(users.Any(x => x.Name == removeUser))
    File.WriteAllLines("db.txt", users.Where(l => l.Name != removedUser).Select(x => $"{x.Name} {x.Id}").ToArray());
else
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid username!");
```

To Remove By Id You may change

```
File.WriteAllLines("db.txt", users.Where(l => l.Name != removedUser).Select(x => $"{x.Name} {x.Id}").ToArray());
```

To

```
File.WriteAllLines("db.txt", users.Where(l => l.Id != removedUser).Select(x => $"{x.Name} {x.Id}").ToArray());
```

Comment: You've lost the second part of the text line. `File.ReadAllLines("db.txt").Where(l => ! l.Split(' ')[0].Contains(removeUser))`. Wille give you The lines as they where filtered so `File.WriteAllLines` doesn't change the file completly

Comment: @DragandDrop Yeah you are right. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I will advice using an object to represent the data you save so your code could be more Meaningfull.

Simply strat with :

```
public class User
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Then Read your file like :

```
static string FilePath = "temp.bak";
static IList<User> Users;

public static bool FileLoad()
{
    Users =
        File.ReadAllLines(FilePath)
            .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
            .Select(line => new User(line))
            .ToList(); ;
    return true;
    //false: try/catch, corrupted users data, invalid file, etc..
}
```

Notice that the filepath and de dataset are outside of the method. because I don't want to copypast file name and path every time and I want to the loaded information to live outside of the loading scope.

And there is a User Constructor that take a line as parameter : it's a simple split.

```
public User(string line)
{
    var data = line.Split('|');
    if (data.Length > 2 || data.Length == 0)
    {
        //Bad Data Throw Error, Roll Kick and Scream. 
    }

    Login = data[0];
    Password = data[1];
}
```

Now the Deletion of an user can be very direct and Clear:

```
Users.Where(u => u.Login != "Login_Test_Delete")
```

We just have to Persist the change in the file:

```
private static bool Save(IEnumerable<User> demoUserSet)
{
    var projection = demoUserSet
                        .Select(x => x.ToString());

    File.WriteAllLines(FilePath, projection);
    return true;

    // Try/Catch for false. Any retry ? etc.
}
```

[LiveDemo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3AqieN)